# Compliment AKS with very large number c++

Tags: c++, binary

We have a project that we have to implement AKS with input is a 128-bit-to-512-bit number (input is hexadecimal and I convert it into binary) in C++.

We can use C++ STL only. I would like to know if there are any binary operations or algorithms that I can refer to to complete this task?

I had tried to convert 512-bit number to int but then I realized it is impossible if using STL only. I have thought of checking whether the number is perfect power by making binary divisions by each number smaller than my input number but it takes too much time.

Comment: (1) By "compliment", do you maybe mean "implement"? (2) What does it mean to "convert 512-bit number to int"? On most systems, `int` is a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Sounds either like XY problem  or "suggest library" problem. Why you even need an 512-bit integral value? If that's hashes\key they are typically represented by strings or arrays of binary values.

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie the input is a string of hexadecimal, and there is a testcase that the number is 512bits large in binary

Comment: @ruakh (1) yes, it's wrong spelling :(( (2) I've tried to convert it into int but then I realized it is impossible because, as you said, int is a a 32-bit integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what is end purpose of using such a value, it's not necessary to treat it as integer. If it is, there are libraries which do that, but they store it internally as a static or dynamic array of bytes (and you can replicate that), and carry perations other byte by byte or in word-long blocks. A lot of vectorizing "magic" may happen there to achieve some sane performance.

If you need some universal storage, probably `std::variant<uint64_t, std::string>` or `std::variant<uint64_t, std::vector< >>` can be a basis. Just store the result of conversion in binary, byte by byte, which is really simple if input is hexadecimal - each pair of characters in input represent a byte of actual value (keeping a possibly omitted leading zero in mind). A conversion from a huge decimal representation into its binary representation would be trickier.